# How to get Updeteable field value and uneditable field value from VF page.

Tags: visualforce, controller

Actually here i am now trying to get the "value" input field's string but the problem is i am switching the text box of value according to the case Field value since few fields don't allow us to edit the data such as case id so i am providing a textbox so that user can enter a value but when i need to fetch that value in "createLogic()" which is there in controller , first i need to check whether the case field is updetable is not if it's not then i will need to get the value from the text box which i am providing for uneditable fields. Can anyone help me out how to do that. 
[image]

VF Page-

```
<apex:page controller="ConditionalPageExtension">
<apex:form id="theForm">
 <apex:pageblock id="thePB" title="Creating Multiple Cases">
  <apex:pageblockButtons >
   <apex:commandButton value="Save" action="{!SaveMultipleCases}"/>
   <apex:commandButton value="Logic" action="{!parseLogic}"/>

  </apex:pageblockButtons>

  <apex:outputPanel id="CaseHead">

   <apex:pageBlockSection columns="1" title="Adding Multiple Cases" id="thePbs" collapsible="False" > 

     <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!waAccList}" var="eachRecord" id="table123" style="width:100%"> 

      <apex:column headerValue="Action">
        <apex:commandLink value="Remove" style="color:red" action="{!removeRowFromAccList}"  rerender="CaseHead" immediate="true" >
             <apex:param value="{!eachRecord.position}" name="rowToRemove" assignTo="{!rowToRemove}"/>
         </apex:commandLink>

      </apex:column>
      <apex:column headerValue="S.No." id="position">
                           <apex:outputText value="{!eachRecord.position}"/> 
       </apex:column>


       <apex:column headerValue="Case Field">
                            <apex:selectList multiselect="false"  size="1" title="select case Field" value="{!eachRecord.CaseFieldSelected}" > 

                    <apex:selectOptions value="{!eachRecord.caseFieldOptions}" />
                    <apex:actionSupport event="onchange"  reRender="table123" />
                </apex:selectList><p/>

       </apex:column>
       <apex:column headerValue="Condition">
                            <apex:selectList multiselect="false"  size="1" title="select case Field"  > 

                    <apex:selectOptions value="{!eachRecord.operatorOptions}" />
                </apex:selectList><p/>
       </apex:column>
        <apex:column headerValue="Case Name" id="demo" style="width:250px">
                           <apex:outputText value="{!eachRecord.caseFieldSelected}"/> 
       </apex:column>
        <apex:column headerValue="Value">
                          <apex:inputField value="{!eachRecord.record[eachRecord.caseFieldSelected]}" rendered="{!casefieldEditablemap[eachRecord.caseFieldSelected]}"  required="false" /> 

                           <apex:inputText value="{!eachRecord.forUneditable}" rendered="{!!casefieldEditablemap[eachRecord.caseFieldSelected]}" />
       </apex:column>


    </apex:pageBlockTable>
   </apex:pageBlockSection>
   <apex:commandButton value="Add More" action="{!addNewRowToAccList}" rerender="CaseHead" Status="status" immediate="true" />


  </apex:outputPanel>
  <apex:pageBlock title="Logic Area" >
    <apex:pageBlockSection >
         <apex:inputField label="Logic" value="{!condLogic.Logic__c}" />
         <apex:OutputField label="Logic Decoding" value="{!condLogic.Logic_Decoding__c}" id="outputString"/>
    </apex:pageBlockSection>      
  </apex:pageBlock>       
 </apex:pageblock>


</apex:form>

</apex:page>
```

Controller-

```
public with sharing class ConditionalPageExtension{

    public map<String,boolean> casefieldEditablemap{get;set;}
    public PageReference SaveMultipleCases() {
    system.debug('controller save method is calling-->');
     ConditionalPageExtensionhelper.save(waAccList);
    return null;
    }

 public Condition_Logic__c condLogic{get;set;}


 public List<WrapperpaCaseList> waAccList {get;set;}
 public Integer rowToRemove {get;set;}

 public ConditionalPageExtension(){
     condLogic= new Condition_Logic__c();
     casefieldEditablemap = new Map<String,Boolean>();
     Map <String, Schema.SObjectField> fieldMap= Case.sObjectType.getDescribe().fields.getMap();
     for(Schema.SObjectField sfield : fieldMap.values()){
           if(!casefieldEditablemap.containskey(string.valueof(sfield.getDescribe().getname()))){
               casefieldEditablemap.put(string.valueof(sfield.getDescribe().getname()),sfield.getDescribe().isUpdateable());
           } 
        }
        system.debug('---->casefieldEditablemap '+casefieldEditablemap);

  waAccList = new List<WrapperpaCaseList>();
  addNewRowToAccList();


 }
 public void removeRowFromAccList(){
  waAccList = ConditionalPageExtensionhelper.removeRowToCaseList(rowToRemove, waAccList);
  integer i=1;
  for(WrapperpaCaseList caseobj1 :waAccList ){
      caseobj1.position=i;
      i++;
  }

 }

 public void addNewRowToAccList(){
     waAccList = addNewRowToAccList(waAccList);
    }

public static List<WrapperpaCaseList> addNewRowToAccList(List<WrapperpaCaseList> waAccObjList){
        WrapperpaCaseList newRecord = new WrapperpaCaseList();
        Case newCaseRecord = new Case();  

       newRecord.record = newCaseRecord;
        newRecord.index = waAccObjList.size();
        newRecord.operatorOptions= new list<selectoption>();
        newRecord.operatorOptions.add(new Selectoption('=','='));
        newRecord.operatorOptions.add(new Selectoption('!=','!='));
        newRecord.caseFieldOptions = new list<selectoption>();
        Map <String, Schema.SObjectField> fieldMap= Case.sObjectType.getDescribe().fields.getMap();
        integer i=1;
        for(Schema.SObjectField sfield : fieldMap.Values()){ 
            if (i==1){
                newRecord.caseFieldSelected =string.valueof(sfield.getDescribe().getname());
                i++;
            }
           newRecord.caseFieldOptions.add(new selectOption(string.valueof(sfield.getDescribe().getname()),string.valueof(sfield.getDescribe().getlabel())));

        }
        newRecord.position = waAccObjList.size()+1;
        waAccObjList.add(newRecord);

      //  casefieldEditablemap = new map<String,Boolean>();

        return waAccObjList;
    }   



 public class WrapperpaCaseList{
        public Integer index {get;set;}
        public Case record {get;set;}
        Public list<selectoption>caseFieldOptions{get;set;}
        Public list<selectoption>operatorOptions{get;set;}
        Public String operatorSelected{get;set;}
        Public String caseFieldSelected{get;set;}
        Public Integer position{get;set;}
        Public boolean isUpdateable{get;set;}
        public String forUneditable {get;set;}
        public String logicTextBox {get;set;}

           public WrapperpaCaseList(){
              isUpdateable = false;
           }

   } 

    public String filter1 { get; set; }
    public String filter2 { get; set; }
    public String filter3 { get; set; }
    public Map<Integer, String> filterMap = new Map<Integer, String>();

    public void createLogic(){

    for(WrapperpaCaseList wa : waAccList)
    {
     if(wa.isUpdateable)
     {
        System.debug('---->>> is updatable'); 
     }
     else{
     System.debug('---->>> is not updatable');

     }


    }

      System.debug('----------->>>inside create');
       /* filter1 = 'Industry__c = \'Agriculture\'';
        filter2 = 'Region_c = \'Asia\'';
        filter3 = 'Partner__c = true';

        filterMap.put(1, filter1);
        filterMap.put(2, filter2);
        filterMap.put(3, filter3);  */
    }

    public void parseLogic(){
    createLogic();
     System.debug('----------->>>inside parse');
       System.debug('----------->>>' + condLogic.Logic__c);
          if(String.isNotBlank(condLogic.Logic__c)){
            String query = 'SELECT Id, Name FROM MyObject__c ';    
            condLogic.Logic_Decoding__c = condLogic.Logic__c;
            for(Integer i = 1; i <= filterMap.size(); i++){
                if(condLogic.Logic_Decoding__c.contains(String.valueOf(i))){
                    condLogic.Logic_Decoding__c = condLogic.Logic_Decoding__c.replace(String.valueOf(i),filterMap.get(i));
                }
            }
            query += ' WHERE (' + condLogic.Logic_Decoding__c + ') ';
            query += ' LIMIT 100';

            condLogic.Logic_Decoding__c = query;
        }


    }



}
```

Helper class-

```
public class ConditionalPageExtensionhelper {

    public static List<ConditionalPageExtension.WrapperpaCaseList> addNewRowToAccList(List<ConditionalPageExtension.WrapperpaCaseList> waAccObjList){
        ConditionalPageExtension.WrapperpaCaseList newRecord = new ConditionalPageExtension.WrapperpaCaseList();
        Case newCaseRecord = new Case();  

       newRecord.record = newCaseRecord;
        newRecord.index = waAccObjList.size();
        newRecord.operatorOptions= new list<selectoption>();
        newRecord.operatorOptions.add(new Selectoption('=','='));
        newRecord.operatorOptions.add(new Selectoption('!=','!='));
        newRecord.caseFieldOptions = new list<selectoption>();
        Map <String, Schema.SObjectField> fieldMap= Case.sObjectType.getDescribe().fields.getMap();
        integer i=1;
        for(Schema.SObjectField sfield : fieldMap.Values()){ 
            if (i==1){
                newRecord.caseFieldSelected =string.valueof(sfield.getDescribe().getname());
                i++;
            }
           newRecord.caseFieldOptions.add(new selectOption(string.valueof(sfield.getDescribe().getname()),string.valueof(sfield.getDescribe().getlabel())));

        }
        newRecord.position = waAccObjList.size()+1;
        waAccObjList.add(newRecord);
        return waAccObjList;
    }


     public static List<ConditionalPageExtension.WrapperpaCaseList> removeRowToCaseList(Integer rowToRemove, List<ConditionalPageExtension.WrapperpaCaseList> waCaseList){
        rowToRemove = rowToRemove-1;
        waCaseList.remove(rowToRemove);
        integer i=1;
       // system.debug('----->'+waCaseList);

        return waCaseList;
    }

    public static void save(List<ConditionalPageExtension.WrapperpaCaseList> waAccList) {
        system.debug('==waAccList==>'+waAccList.size());
        List<Case> CaseRecordsToBeInserted = new List<Case>();
        if(waAccList !=null && !waAccList.isEmpty()){
            for(ConditionalPageExtension.WrapperpaCaseList eachRecord : waAccList ){
      //          Case accTemp = eachRecord.record;
        //        CaseRecordsToBeInserted.add(accTemp);

            }
            system.debug('==CaseRecordsToBeInserted==>'+CaseRecordsToBeInserted.size());
            insert CaseRecordsToBeInserted;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: so you want to check if the field is updated or not? use describe call to check field is updatable or not

Comment: okay, and then i also need to get the value of that input Field since i am switching the input fields according to isUpdateable so how to get that. @Ratan

Comment: if possible can we chat @Ratan

Comment: http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/39000/how-to-get-updeteable-field-value-and-uneditable-field-value-from-vf-page